# SharePoint PowerShell Document Library properties

Tags: document-library, powershell

I'm pretty new to PowerShell and try to collect the following data about every document library in a site-collection:

1. Document Library Name
2. Created Date
3. Content Type

Are there any general improvements i could do to the code? Are there any other way of getting the name of the content type?

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -erroraction SilentlyContinue 

$siteURL = "https://contoso.com/sites/projects"
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) 
{
    foreach($list in $web.Lists)
    {
        if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
        {
        $listName = $list.Title
        $listCreatedDate = $list.Created
        $listContentType = $list.ContentTypes
        $listContentTypeName = $listContentType.Name

        write-host "List name: $listName"
        write-host "List created: $listCreatedDate"
        write-host "List content type: $listContentTypeName"
    }
}
}
$web.Dispose();
$site.Dispose();
```

Comment: `$list.ContentTypes` returns a `SPContentTypeCollection`.  If one of your document library contains more than one content type, `$listContentType.Name` will return `$null`.  Also, if there are no content types, or if content types are not enabled, `$listContentType` will likely be `$null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize the following pattern to inventory SharePoint objects (converted example):

```
Get-SPSite $siteURL |
Select -ExpandProperty AllWebs |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists | Where { $_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" } |
Select Title, Created, ContentTypes
```

Comment: Excellent! Clean and simple output

Comment: One thing i noticed is that while running the script in powershell, the select statement for ContentTypes is displayed correctly but while trying to export it to a csv file, it returns "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection" instead of the content type name.

Answer (score 1):

Try below piece in your code.

```
if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
{
 foreach ($ctype in $list.ContentTypes)  
 {  

        write-host "List name:" $list.Title
        write-host "List created:" $list.Created
        write-host "List content type:" $ctype.Name
  }
}
```

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Find-Lists-or-Libraries-fd247709